# writing c++ program "fraction of double"

Tags: c++, fractions

I wanna write a c++ program that read a double value and after reading it print only the fraction of that number, for example if the input was 14.25 then the output must be 0.25
should include iomanip to it?

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried so far? Where specifically did you get stuck while writing this yourself?

Comment: To get just the decimal, you can subtract off the integer part of the number which will leave just the decimal. For example `double fraction = value - static_cast<int>(value);` plus some additional logic to handle negative numbers.

Comment: I'd avoid using numerical representations of your input at all. I'd 1) read a line of user input, 2) verify that it only contains `'0'` - `'9'`, `'.'`, with a potential single leading `'+'` or `'-'`, 3) replace everything before the equal sign with a single `'0'`, 4) display the remaining. This approach will let you handle as much precision as your input stream can handle

Comment: `fmod` or `modf` might also help.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to

1. Round the number down to the nearest integer - you can use the floor() function (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/floor/)
2. Subtract that integer from the original number to get the result